# Настройка тройного запроса к Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//запрос
//подставляем металл нужному id
//запрос - полностью работает
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.assoc as metal,
FROM
    tovar t1
LEFT JOIN
    tovar_assoc t2 ON t2.position=t1.metal WHERE t2.num=9

//работает и это
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t3.assoc as proba
FROM
    tovar t1
LEFT JOIN
    tovar_assoc t3 ON t3.position=t1.proba WHERE t3.num=10

//не работает...
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.assoc as metal,
    t3.assoc as proba
FROM
    tovar t1
LEFT JOIN
    tovar_assoc t2 ON t2.position=t1.metal WHERE t2.num=9
LEFT JOIN
    tovar_assoc t3 ON t3.position=t1.proba WHERE t3.num=10
```

собственно, может кто подсказать, как построить запрос с 2мя LEFT_JOIN'ами? (Оба левтжойна идут от одной таблицы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
...
LEFT JOIN
tovar_assoc t2 ON t2.position=t1.metal AND t2.num=9
LEFT JOIN
tovar_assoc t3 ON t3.position=t1.proba AND t3.num=10
```

Comment: Оно самое ) Только по логике должно было быть WHERE, а оказалось AND